# Why does typedef struct allow default initializer?

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, initialization, typedef

So, structs can have default initializers. As far as I understand, however, typedefs should not be able to.  Nonetheless, the following compiles (C++11, g++ 5.4, 6, and 7).

```
typedef struct {
  uint8_t   foo[6] = {'M', 'A', 'R', 'K', 'E', 'R'};
  uint8_t   bar;
  uint32_t  baz; 
} MyStruct;
```

Is the compiler defining and declaring an anonymous struct of type MyStruct with a default initialzer for foo? If so, are bar and baz zero-initialized or uninitialized (CLion warns that bar and baz are uninitialized, but I suspect that is erroneous)? Is this undefined behavior, a g++ extension, or a feature of the language?

Comment: How's this any different from `struct MyStruct { /* same stuff here */ };`? The default member initializers don't come into the picture until you create an instance of `MyStruct`.

Comment: `typedef struct {} S;` is the same as `struct A {}; typedef A S;`. There is no reason why it should fail.

Comment: Such initializers are used when generating implicit member initialization in class constructors. How is your struct different from any other class? `typedef` is completely inconsequential here.

Comment: There's no particular reason to use `typedef` for a structure in C++. Just write `struct MyStruct { ... };`. (C has different rules.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far as I understand, however, typedefs should not be able to [have default initializers].

`typedef` is just an alias of a type. It can alias a type that has default *member* initializers.

```
typedef struct {
  uint8_t   foo[6] = {'M', 'A', 'R', 'K', 'E', 'R'};
  uint8_t   bar;
  uint32_t  baz; 
} MyStruct;
```

`struct {...}` is a definition of a struct  (i.e. a class). The struct definition is within a typedef definition.

> Is the compiler defining and declaring an anonymous struct ... with a default initialzer ...?

Yes. structs can have default *member* initializers. Whether the struct is unnamed or named is irrelevant.

> Is this undefined behavior, a g++ extension, or a feature of the language?

It's well defined standard feature.

---

It's curious how the C++11 addition of default member initializers allow non-default construction of members of unnamed structs (i.e. classes) - as earlier only place for member initializers was in the member initialization list of a constructor, and there is no syntax for declaring a constructor for an unnamed struct.